# Input value is "" when the entered input starts with a space

Tags: javascript, input

Entering a space before anything in my input results in the value being read through JavaScript to be empty. When I have other spaces in the middle it isn't empty but when I put a space in at the beginning after typing in some text the text isn't shown in the debugger on the input value.

The javascript

```
    inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".report_info > div > input");
    console.log(inputs);    
    for(let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
        inputs[i].classList += " empty";

        inputs[i].addEventListener("input", evt=>{
            evt.preventDefault();
            value = inputs[i].value.trim();
            if(value)
                inputs[i].classList.remove("empty");
            else
                if(!inputs[i].classList.contains("empty"))
                    inputs[i].classList += " empty";
        })
    }
```

The html this should work on

```html
    <div class="report_info">
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="students_name" required>    
            <label for="students_name">
                <span>Student's Name</span>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="student_id" required>
            <label for="student_id">
                <span>ID</span>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="email" name="parent_phone" required>
            <label for="parent_phone">
                <span>Parent's Tele #</span>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="semester_year" required>
            <label for="semester_year">
                <span>Semester/Year</span>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="number" name="days_present" required>
            <label for="days_present">
                <span>Days Present</span>
            </label>
        </div>
```

Comment: `.trim()` removes spaces at the beginning and end.

Comment: If the input only contains a space, `.trim()` will remove it, so it will be empty.

Comment: That's not the issue. The issue is anything following a space at the beginning always gives me a value of ""

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/91skzj4d/2/

Comment: I've added the html this should work on and the rest of the javascript I'm using that pertains to this section. I think the code should be able to work with all of this.

Comment: I've found that this issue is present when the input type is `number`. Could this mean it isn't returning the value because its expecting a number?

Comment: I've checked it with Barmar's js fiddle and its the type that was causing the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the issue was that the value of my inputs with type "number" were invalid they just returned nothing. This means that if the user suddenly enters a letter or unaccepted character after a string of valid numbers the value will then be empty.

Comment: Chrome won't even let me type things that aren't numbers into this type of input.

Comment: you can still put them in on firefox